# Bunch of stars moving on sky in triangular and different other shapes

Tags: star, amateur-observing

Today I saw different Stars are moving on the sky in shapes of triangle and some randomly. its about 4:20 am in Nasarpur Pakistan and last star I saw at 4:32 am. They are moving in direction (North 345) degrees. Any one told me what is it?

I also saw some stars moving in other direction and they are very bright. I observed them they are near to earth w.r.t to other non moving stars ?